# Javascript 2D Array TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays

maybe only a very simple mistake but i need your help.

```
var x,y = 0;
```

working code:

```
array[x][y] = 10;
```

wrong code:

```
array[x + 1][y] = 10;
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The Array:

```
var array= [
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
];
```

---

Its definitely not a "ArrayOutOfBounds".

If i call this function in the google chrome console there is no error...

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with this if we don't know what `x` and `y` are? You've said it's not an array out of bounds issue, but that's what the error and symptom suggest to me it is. `x` is clearly `9`, so `x+1` is `10`, and you have no array at `array[10]`.

Comment: Re your edit adding `var x,y = 0;`: [*Neither* array access expression works](https://jsfiddle.net/91wqsLLr/) (including the one you said works), because `x` has the value `undefined`, and `array[undefined]` is `undefined`, so we can't read `[y]` from it. If we change it to `var x = 0, y = 0;`, *both* expressions work: https://jsfiddle.net/91wqsLLr/1/

Answer (score 0):

One of my error was that x and y was a String, so i need to parse it. 
The other mistake (thank you "T.J. Crowder") was my definition of my variables used (here z1 and z2).

```
x = parseInt(x);
y = parseInt(y);

var z1 = 0;
var z2 = 0;

...

z1=x+1:
z2=y;

...

array[z1][z2] = 10;
```

Now it works

Comment: Ah! So since `x` was (say) `"2"`, `x + 1` was `"21"` and you had no entry in the array at index 21. :-)